# Algortimo VisualG: desconsiderar número 0

Tags: visualg

Estou resolvendo o seguinte exercício:

> Escreva um algoritmo que calcule a média dos números digitados pelo usuário, se eles forem pares. Termine a leitura se o usuário digitar zero (0)

Porém, quando eu digito o 0 para terminar, ele esta contando o 0 como numero par, e esta dividindo por um número a mais.

```
algoritmo "semnome"

var
n,np,m,nnp:real
inicio
repita
escreval ("entre com um numero")
leia (n)
se n%2=0 entao
np<-np+1
nnp<-nnp+n
fimse
ate n=0
m<- nnp/np
escreval ("a media dos numeros é",m)
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Acrescente um `e n diferente de 0` ao `se`.

Comment: O operador diferente é `<>`; portanto, adicione `e n <> 0` ao `se`

Answer (score 4):

Só adicionar um critério na condição:

> Se o número **não for zero** (for diferente de zero) e se o resto da divisão por 2 for igual a zero.

Só pra deixar umas dicas: atente à formatação do código, indentação. Isso é importante. Dê nomes realmente úteis às variáveis, ninguém gosta de ter que ler o código inteiro para entender o que a variável `np` significa no escopo e, acredite, você também não vai gostar de fazer isso quando for ler seu código antigo.

```
algoritmo "semnome"

var
numero, qtd, media, soma: real

inicio

repita
   escreval ("entre com um numero")
   leia (numero)
   se (numero diferente de 0) E (numero % 2 = 0) entao
      qtd <- qtd + 1
      soma <- soma + numero
   fimse
ate numero = 0

media <- soma/qtd

escreval ("a media dos numeros é", media)
fimalgoritmo
```